# Summation verification

Tags: polynomials, notation, summation, products, symmetric-functions

I have a particular polynomial

$$ 1-10x+35x^2-50x^3 $$

Which can be written nicely as

$$1-(1+2+3+4)x+(1\cdot2+1\cdot3+1\cdot4+2\cdot3+2\cdot4+3\cdot4)x^2$$
$$+(1\cdot2\cdot3+1\cdot2\cdot4+1\cdot3\cdot4+2\cdot3\cdot4)x^3$$

I can write the coefficients as a pattern using summation notation as

$$\sum_{1\le j_1<...<j_4\le4}\frac{4!}{j_1\cdot...\cdot j_4}-\sum_{1\le j_1<j_2<j_3\le4}\frac{4!}{j_1\cdot j_2\cdot j_3}x+\sum_{1\le j_1<j_2\le4}\frac{4!}{j_1\cdot j_2}x^2-\sum_{1\le j_1\le4}\frac{4!}{j_1}x^3$$

I would like to condense this down in to a single double summation.  I think I can handle it by doing

$$4!\sum_{k=1}^{4}\sum_{1\le j_1\lt ...j_{5-k}\le 4}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{j_1\cdot...\cdot 
j_k}$$

a)  Is this notation okay?  What i mean is, it the notation correct mathematically?

b)  Is there an easier way to write this?

EDIT:  I made a slight error in the denominator.  I think this fixes is.

$$4!\sum_{k=1}^{4}\sum_{1\le j_1\lt ...j_{5-k}\le 4}\frac{(-x)^{k-1}}{j_1\cdot...\cdot 
j_{5-k}}$$

EDIT 2:  I came across the generalized harmonic numbers defined as
$$H_{n,j}=\sum_{1\le k_1<...,<k_j\le n}\frac{1}{k_1\cdot...\cdot k_j}$$

Therefore I can write the above double sum using this definition as

$$4!\sum_{j=0}^3H_{4,4-j}x^j$$

Comment: Not an answer but in case it helps the polynomial is $(4x-1)(3x-1)(2x-1)(x-1)-24x^4$. Also the coefficients are elementary symmetric functions, and there are conventional ways of expressing those using efficient notation - would that be what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that would actually be quite useful.  A quick question, is the summation correct?

Comment: So in the general case the polynomial would be $\prod_{k=1}^m(1-kx)-m!x^m$?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Define "*okay*"!

Comment: Ha ha.  Yeah I guess that's not a great math word...  I'm wondering if the notation is correct.  I also am looking for other ways to write it because i feel there are.  @MarkBennet showed another way which seems better, but I also was curious of other ways as well.